# Как устроены многоуровневые таблицы виртуальной памяти?

Tags: c++, виртуальная-память

[image: Дерево таблиц]

Если каждая запись в каталоге является обычной ссылкой на каталог (чит. таблицу) уровня ниже, допустим Каталог уровня 4 с некоторой записью будет содержать ссылку на Каталог уровня 3 для некоторого процесса. Вопрос: зачем нам более одной записи в Каталоге уровня 4, учитывая, что все записи эквивалентны (ссылки на Каталог уровня 3)?

Comment: а какое это имеет отношение к с++? и где именно была взята эта картинка?

Comment: К слову, из приведенных в вопросе данных совершенно не очевидно, что записи эквивалентны. В вопросе нигде не указано, что может быть лишь один каталог уровня 3, а потому записи в каталоге уровня 4 могут различаться, ссылаясь на различные каталоги уровня 3.

Comment: http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/hard/memory/memory-4-2.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Данная архитектура возникает для решения противоречия: (1) Обращение к памяти должно быть как можно более быстрым. Нужно гарантировать O(1) - в худшем случае, иначе невозможно построение систем реального времени. (2) Адресация памяти, сама по себе, не должна тратить много памяти. Количество физической памяти, может быть существенно меньше адресного пространства, а процессов с независимыми адресными пространствами - много. (3) желательно, без ветвлений и сложной логики (это все в железе "программировать").

Например, если у нас есть адресное пространство 2^64 байт, и страница памяти 64K = 2^16 байт, значит всего возможно 2^48 страниц. Если мы хотим обойтись одним каталогом, то как этот каталог должен быть устроен?

Самый быстрый способ - достать элемент из массива по номеру. Значит заводим массив размером 2^48 Но тогда для каждого процесса потребуется (2^48)*8 байт физической памяти, только под нужды менеджера памяти. Неприемлемо.

Можно хранить в каталоге только только записи о выделенных страницах памяти. На выбор: сортированный массив, хеш таблица,  сбалансированное дерево  - не гарантируют O(1)-в худшем (только амортизированное среднее O(1)). Неприемлемо.

Цифровой бор (trie), внезапно, обеспечивает O(1), но с о-очень большой константой (если реализовывать его c ветвлением на каждый бит). Кроме того, собственные аллокации  менеджера памяти будут требовать много меньше страницы памяти, что тоже нежелательно.

В общем, текущая архитектура это tires - переросток: суть дерево с четырьмя уровнями ветвления, и с числом ветвления равным 2^12 дочерних элементов, на каждом уровне ветвления. Ветвления на каждом уровне - с использованием массива, и доступом к элементу по его порядковому номеру. (Каждый массив как раз помещается в страницу памяти.)

Разумеется, разные записи в таблице 4-го уровня указывают на разные таблицы 3-го уровня. (Иллюстрация неудачная.) Некоторые записи в каждой таблице - никуда не ведут (равны null), поэтому количество памяти требуемое менеджером памяти примерно пропорционально реальному использованию памяти. Поскольку, как правило, память выделяется в близко праположенных частях адресного пространства расходы менеджера, оказываются много меньше выделенной памяти. но, последнее утверждение - не гарантируется.

Comment: Вы имели в виду Trie?

Comment: Для 4К таблиц получаем 512 8-ми байтных элементов на одной странице каждого уровня. . Т.е. ветвление идет по 9-ти битам виртуального адреса. Последние 12 бит это смещение в странице памяти с данными. / Кстати, неплохо бы для полноты понимания процесса трансляции в ответ сведения о TLB (кэш адресов трансляции) добавить